# Maximum distinct elements after removing k elements

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, hash, heap

This is the link of geeksforgeeks question
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/maximum-distinct-elements-after-removing-k-elements/0

THis   is my code-

```
import collections
import heapq
def maxoccur(arr,k):
   c = 0
   d = collections.Counter(arr)
   heap = [(value,key) for key,value in d.items()]
   heapq.heapify(heap)
   while(heap):
     x = heapq.heappop(heap)

     if x[0] == 1:
        c+=1
     elif x[0]>1 and k>0:
        k-=1
        y = x[0]-1
        heapq.heappush(heap,(y,x[1]))
     elif k<=0:
        break
    if k == 0:
        while(heap):
            x = heapq.heappop(heap)
            if x[0] == 1:
               c+=1
    elif k>0:
       c-=k
    
    return c
```

What is wrong in my code I am getting wrong answer in this test case-

Input:
84 47
28 26 24 26 17 13 10 2 3 8 21 20 24 17 1 7 23 17 12 9 28 10 3 21 3 14 8 26 30 13 13 19 30 28 14 17 2 23 10 4 22 30 15 8 9 15 6 1 24 17 2 21 27 4 3 21 17 2 16 16 15 28 27 6 17 10 14 18 25 16 13 16 15 28 15 15 4 21 8 19 7 9 9 25

Its Correct output is:
27

And Your Code's output is:
25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler approach is based on fact, that we first can remove any items with occurency count > 1 without changing of distinct values count, then remove some of the rest ones - now distinct values count becomes less.

```
def maxoccur(arr,k):
    lena = len(arr)
    lens = len(set(arr))
    excess = lena - lens
    return lens if excess >= k else max(0, lena - k)
```

---

old answer as transformation of author's code

Note that heap is minheap, and I made it quasi-maxheap with negation of counters.
Then we just make k (if possible) operations of decreasing counters and look for the rest in heap.

Source values are not needed at all in the heap, but I'm too lazy to change code.

```
import collections
import heapq
def maxoccur(arr,k):
    d = collections.Counter(arr)
    heap = [(-value, key) for key,value in d.items()]
    heapq.heapify(heap)
    while (heap) and (k > 0):
        k -= 1
        x = heapq.heappop(heap)
        if x[0] < -1:
            heapq.heappush(heap,(x[0]+1,x[1]))
    return len(heap)

k = 47
arr = [int(i) for i in '28 26 24 26 17 13 10 2 3 8 21 20 24 17 1 7 23 17 12 9 28 10 3 21 3 14 8 26 30 13 13 19 30 28 14 17 2 23 10 4 22 30 15 8 9 15 6 1 24 17 2 21 27 4 3 21 17 2 16 16 15 28 27 6 17 10 14 18 25 16 13 16 15 28 15 15 4 21 8 19 7 9 9 25'.split()]
print(maxoccur(arr,k))

arr = [5, 7, 5, 5, 1, 2, 2]
k = 3
print(maxoccur(arr,k))

>>>
27
4
```

Comment: Ok your code is running but can you plz tell me what is wrong in my code ? It will be great help Thank you

Comment: @Pratyush Narain Logic with extracting the smallest counters is too complex. You extract   single elements first, decrease counters for multiple occurences - so some of them (smaller ones!!!) become single too. So I am not sure that decreasing larger counters is made correct.

Comment: OK i have a doubt here we want to return maximum possible distinct occurrence. And we are making maxheap. Suppose we have k=1 we have array as 5,5,5,2,2,1 so according to your code we will pop 5 first, K will become 0 and we will be having our final array as 5,5,2,2,1 with only one distinct element. But we can get 5,5,5,2,1 with 2 distinct occurrence.  Is my logic correct? If so then why are we using max heap?

Comment: To provide maximum possible distinct items, we need to "cut" items with the most occurence count (or just all counters>1) - this process does not diminish distinct count as long as possible

Comment: In example with 5,5,5,2,2,1 we have 3 distinct **values** 1,2,5. After removing 5 we still have 3 distinct values. For k=4 we remove (decrease counters) in that order: 5, 5 again, 2, and finally we remove any (depends on heap state) from 1,2,5, so result is 2 distinct values

Comment: Didn't understand what are u saying

Comment: OK, once again, step by step. Array  [5,5,5,2,2,1] contains 3 distinct values 1,2 and 5. Is it clear?

Comment: Look at shorter solution.